# Dropdown list in Excel using data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Intend to create a dropdown list that will have options 1 to 4.

[image]

Not getting anything visible in D1.

[image]

Although the dropdown is taking values only 1-4, but the same not visible during entry. It will help if the user gets to see that he or she can only enter between  1-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following settings:

- Allow: List
- Source: `1, 2, 3, 4`
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

**Data Validation Settings**

[image: List Source]

**List Output**

[image: List Output]